# Datepicker - invalid date & class style

Tags: datepicker, ng-bootstrap

Following your sample code

```
  <div class="col-6">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                 name="d2" #c2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="model2" ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" (click)="d2.toggle()" type="button">
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <hr/>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" (click)="model2 = null">Select Today</button>
    <hr/>


    <pre>M: {{ model2 | json }}</pre>
    <pre>S: {{ c2.status }}</pre>
    <pre>B: {{ c2.status==INVALID }}</pre>
  </div>
```

works fine. But I want to set an error-class for the whole `input-group`, something like

```
<div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error':isInValid }">
```

But the evalutation of the `c2.status` never evaltuates to `true/false` dynamically. It remains unchanged ==> How to make a proper compare to set the class dynamically?

Comment: Works fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2dsstd?file=app/datepicker-popup.html. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue, as I just did.

Comment: and if you add the last line of my code above you'll see that it evaluates always to `false` (instead of depending on the `c2.status`

Comment: Which last line? `c2.status==INVALID`? What is the value of the property INVALID of your component? If your goal is to compare the status to the **string** 'INVALID', then it should be `c2.status === 'INVALID'`. With quotes.

Comment: Yeah - true... I missed that part :-/ Since I'm not familiar with the current implementation: Is there anywhere a hint if this text remain? Or is there some entity which is better suited for compare? ANYWAY - thx for the hint - could have figured it out on my own :-(

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to test if the control is invalid? The easiest way is `c2.invalid`. https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: yeah - this one... thx a lot - I'll update by an answer - you helped me VERY much - thx

Answer (score 0):

Thx to JB Nizet I figured out the following proper syntax:

`<div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': c2.invalid }">`